# Sharepoint list items getting auto modified

Tags: list, splistitem, modified

Sharepoint list items getting auto modified. All the lists seems modified by a single user. But when checked with the user, he hasn't accessed this list at all. And the modified time stamps are all the same. 100s of items got modified at the same time, which is not possible manually. 
Any help on this would be really helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is a timerjob updating the list items? Usually timerjobs run under the same user as the OWSTimer, but a custom timerjob might open the site using a specific UserToken or something similar...

Or is a feature overwriting/recreating the mentioned items during activation?

Some more information would be useful. Like: is it a productive system or your test environment?

Comment: Thanks for the response Markus. This is a production environment with over 1.5 lac users. How can I confirm that a timer job is responsible for this. Please advice. And i believe there is no feature as you asked. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned features for development / testing environments, where lists could be recreated, when a feature is activated.

Comment: The correct timer job (if it really is a timer job causing the mentioned modifications), might be difficult to find. Are there any custom timer jobs? I would check them first! To find the correct timerjob, check if any last run time matches the modification time on the list items.

The `Get-SPTimerJob` powershell command might be useful. It will print the last run time for all timer jobs. Be sure to use the SharePoint management Shell or to run `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"` first.

Comment: Okay. I'll try this and let you know the updates. Markus, is there any way to figure out why these modifications happened under this particular user. And please let us know of any alternative for get-sptimerjob using stsadm

Comment: Well you can also use SharePoint's Central Admin > Monitoring > TimerJobs instead of the Shell. But the last run time is not immediately visible, I assume.

If it really is one of the timer jobs, you will have to check its code. Maybe a user is hard coded there? Would be very strange bug!
Maybe it is something completely different...

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all these info. I'll try all these suggestions and check for the possibility for such a bug. Will keep this thread posted with the findings. Thanks.

Comment: A little more background: I assume, that some timerjob uses `SPListItem.Update()` instead of `SPListItem.SystemUpdate()`. The last one will not update the modification date. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx).

Comment: There is very high chances of this due to some custom code. Have a look at what all custom feature is installed at site collection or web application level. 
You should once check whether that list or site contains any custom SharePoint Designer Workflow which contains any impersonation step which might be doing this.

Comment: Yes. We do have a custom workflow for this list which led to multiple email notification for all these modifications too. So could you please suggest the possible causes? Syncing tasks with outlook is one cause within my limited knowledge. Any other ?

Comment: If you have the code base, search for the `SPListItem.Update()` call within an impersonation. The impersonation is either something like:

    `using(SPSite s = new SPSite(url, usertoken)) { /*...*/ }`
or
    `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => { /*...*/ });`

Something like this is most probably the reason.

Comment: Alright. I'll check. But let me point out my basic issue. How come all the  modified by shows this particular users name where he has not accessed This list for months.

Comment: Hi all, I checked with the timer jobs and was able to confirm that they were not responsible for this. Any other possible cause? Any help would be really helpful as this issue is now ongoing for several days in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Turns out it was a synchronisation issue with Outlook. If you have a list or Calendar linked to Outlook, then all items will be modified during synchronisation. Remove the list/calendar in question from Outlook.